# CSS transition glitch

Tags: css, translation

I have an issue with my CSS transition. I created a user profile design, and when a user hovers over the profile photo, the border changes its width from 3px to 10px. This results in the entire site shaking on the transition.

[**Shaking can be seen here!**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ozodrukh/mvY4k/)

**CSS**

```
#timeline-user > .timeline-user-border{
    border: 3px solid #2cbbee;
    padding: 7px;
    border-radius: 35px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease;
}

#timeline-user > .timeline-user-border:hover{
    border: 10px solid #2cbbee;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

basically the additional math of adding and removing paddings and borders causes alot of confusion. you can negate this by including the border and padding.

SOLUTION:
http://jsfiddle.net/mvY4k/2/

Hope this helps with your problem and any other related ones! Please let me know if you have any other questions! :)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/04/26/css3-transitions-thank-god-specification/#a11) from Smashing Magazine:

> Transitioning multiple properties is not synchronized in Firefox and Webkit. You can [see in this example](http://jsbin.com/uxenaz/1) how making the border smaller by the same amount that the padding increases (and vice versa) causes the following content to shake a bit. IE 10 and Opera get this right.

And in fact if you change:

```
-webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease;
```

to:

```
-webkit-transition:width 0.2s ease;
```

You'll notice that your elements no longer shake.

I don't know of a solution, though, and if I had the rep I would've posted this as a comment.

Comment: I am on Opera and I can see the shake too. So I guess it is for all Webkit based browsers :)

Comment: I was getting all sorts of crazy animation glitches when I had it set to all.  Transitioning only one property fixed that.  Nice!

Answer (score 0):

use box-shadow :

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mvY4k/4/

```
   #timeline-user > .timeline-user-border{
        border: 3px solid #2cbbee;
        padding: 7px;
        border-radius: 35px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease;
    }

    #timeline-user > .timeline-user-border:hover{
        -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 10px #2cbbee;
        -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 10px #2cbbee;
        box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 10px #2cbbee;
    }
```

even more simple http://jsfiddle.net/qRJQY/1/

```
<div class="timeline-user-line">
    <img src=http://api.randomuser.me/0.2/portraits/men/32.jpg />
</div>
```

the style:

```
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}


.timeline-user-line{
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position:relative;
    border: 3px solid #2cbbee;
     -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 0px #2cbbee;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 0px #2cbbee;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 0px #2cbbee;
}

.timeline-user-line:before,.timeline-user-line:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;

}
.timeline-user-line:before{
    background:#2cbbee;
    height: 2px;
    width: 40px;
    right:-50px;
    top:20px;
}

.timeline-user-line img{
    width:80%;
    height:80%;
    position:absolute;
    left:10%;
    top:10%;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.timeline-user-line:hover{
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 10px #2cbbee;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 10px #2cbbee;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 10px #2cbbee;
}
```