# CSS transition padding glitch in webkit browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, css-transitions

When I use padding in a css transition, webkit browsers (safari osx, Chrome osx & Chrome windows) have a little glitch at the start and the end of each transition, resulting in a 1px movement of elements placed after the animated element.

http://jsfiddle.net/QG4QV/19/

HTML

```
test test test <span class="test">Hover me</span> test test test test
```

CSS

```
.test{
  color:#FFF;
  background:#000;
  padding:4px 4px 4px 30px;
  transition: padding 0.5s linear;
}

.test:hover{
  padding:4px 30px 4px 4px;
}
```

I've searched and tried various solutions, but nothing solves this example?!
[CSS transition glitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921525/css-transition-glitch)
[CSS transition effect makes image blurry / moves image 1px, in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464055/css-transition-effect-makes-image-blurry-moves-image-1px-in-chrome)

(Example filled with possible solutions: http://jsfiddle.net/QG4QV/18/ , but nothing works)

Answer (score 5):

I do not know if there is another explanation for the glitch. I would guess that the animation of padding values is causing rounding inconsistencies during the transitioning which have an affect on the overall width of the `.test` element.

I found that the following CSS fixes it for me in Chrome33.

```
test {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3kSGY/)

**Edit:** So looking at the element in the [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/), without `display:inline-block` the *"Hover Me"* text itself has a `width=auto` and `height=auto` computed style.

With the `inline-block` the text has a computed style of `width=60` and `height=20`. I think it is this *hard* computed style that stops the transition glitching.

Comment: Sadly in Safari the problem remains

Comment: Ah, sorry I haven't got Safari here to test with. I'll try another machine later.